# AngularJS, MVC.Unknown provider: $ScopeProvider <- $Scope <- userCtrl

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting an error with my angularscript where i'm trying to load some data from a web api and trying use ng-repeat to understand the basics of Angular.
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$ScopeProvider%20%3C-%20$Scope%20%3C-%20userCtrl

My code looks like this

i have an app.js that loads from _Layout.cshtml which only consists of:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

then my user-controller.js also loads from _Layout.cshtml looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('userCtrl', ['$Scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loading = true;

        $http.get('/api/user')
            .success(function (data) {
        $scope.users = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    }).error(function () {
        $scope.error = "An error has occured while loading posts!";
        $scope.loading = false;

    });
    }]);
```

And then this is what my HTML looks like:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<html ng-app="myApp" >
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>

</head>
<body ng-controller ="userCtrl">
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <div class="container">

        <div ng-repeat="user in userCtrl.users">
            First name: {{user.FirstName}}<br />
            Last name: {{user.LastName}}<br />
            Age: {{user.Age}}<br />
            City: {{user.City}}

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/usercontroller").Include(
                "~/Scripts/App/user-controller.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularjs").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/App/app.js"));
```

and then i have this in the _Layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/usercontroller")
```

My problem was that in in the ng-repeat i had "user in userCtrl.users" i changed it to "user in users" since the controller was already defined in the  and now it seems to be working :)

Comment: did u load angularjs script file as well?

Comment: Yes, they are all loaded through my BundleConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to inject dependency with capital "Scope", also you don't need to inject $http as dependency.

If your controller look like :

```
.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $http) {
```

it should be fixed.

Comment: Haha wow, thanks. Now my all my .js files loads fine but when i load the page i can see the <div> with ng-repeat appear really fast but just to disappear..

Comment: @howDisWorks it's normal to see ng-repeat until angular initializes. But if you are not seeing the data you are expecting, make sure you are getting the data with no error. Also in your ng-repeat you don't need to write userCtrl.users, it needs to be just "users"